# Scala method optimization

Tags: scala, optimization, tail-recursion

I'm having a def that is recursively called and I'm using a bunch of cases.
I'm wondering is there is any nice solution to get rid of that cases, without losing the readability of the definition.

```
 @tailrec
  def getElements(existent:List[List[String]], proposed: List[List[String]], result: List[(String,List[String])]): List[(String, List[String])]= {

    proposed match {
      case head :: tail => {
        existent.find(element => identicalOfMatch(element, head)) match {

          case Some(elem) => getElements(existent.filterNot(e => e == elem), tail, ("Same", elem) :: result)
          case None =>   {
            existent.find(element => noneOfMatch(element, head) && canDelete(proposed, element)) match {

              case Some(elem) => getElements(existent.filterNot(e => e == elem), head::tail, ("Delete", elem) :: result)
              case None => {
                existent.find(element => firstOfMatch(element, head)) match {

                  case Some(elem) => getElements(existent.filterNot(e => e == elem), tail, ("Update", head) :: result)
                  case None => {
                    existent.find(element => anyOfMatch(element, head) && firstOfNotPresent(proposed, head.head) && firstOfNotPresent(existent, head.head)) match {

                      case Some(elem) =>  getElements(existent.filterNot(e => e == elem), tail, ("Update", head) :: result)

                      case None =>        getElements(Nil, Nil, existent.map(element => ("Deleted", element)) ::: proposed.map(element => ("Created", element)) ::: result)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      case Nil => result
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try to divide each case in a smaller function

Comment: Can you share your functions? Or at least their signatures? (`identicalOfMatch`, `noneOfMatch`,`canDelete`... )

Comment: All that functions are A => Boolean or (A, B)=> Boolean and their responsability are to filter out some cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method readability would benefit greatly if you could split it into several methods.
Unfortunately, you can't do that if you want your function to be tail-recursive.

But there is a solution which is called [trampoline](https://medium.com/@olxc/trampolining-and-stack-safety-in-scala-d8e86474ddfa), which would allow you to create an arbitrarily deep chain of function recursive calls which are stack-safe.

Trampolines are implemented in Scala standard library in package `scala.util.control.TailCalls`. I reimplemented your method to take advantage of it.

First thing I did was removing an accumulator parameter from `getElements`, we won't need it anymore.

Then I split `getElements` into three functions. I called nested functions `ifNoneMatched` and `ifNoneMatched2` but you could probably come up with more meaningful names.

Then I wrapped every call to a function which is in the chain into `tailcall` and every constant into `done` (in our case `Nil`). When I needed to append something to list returned from a recursive call I used `flatMap` from `TailRec`.

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def getElements(existent:List[List[String]], proposed: List[List[String]]): TailRec[List[(String, List[String])]]= {

    proposed match {
      case head :: tail => {
        existent.find(element => identicalOfMatch(element, head)) match {
          case Some(elem) => tailcall(getElements(existent.filterNot(e => e == elem), tail).map(("Same", elem) :: _))
          case None => tailcall(ifNoneMatched(head, tail, existent, proposed))
        }
      }
      case Nil => done(Nil)
    }
}

def ifNoneMatched(head: List[String], tail: List[List[String]], existent:List[List[String]], proposed: List[List[String]]): TailRec[List[(String, List[String])]] = {
    existent.find(element => noneOfMatch(element, head) && canDelete(proposed, element)) match {

      case Some(elem) => tailcall(getElements(existent.filterNot(e => e == elem), proposed)).map(("Delete", elem) :: _)
      case None => tailcall(ifNoneMatched2(head, tail, existent, proposed))
    }
}

def ifNoneMatched2(head: List[String], tail: List[List[String]], existent:List[List[String]], proposed: List[List[String]]): TailRec[List[(String, List[String])]] = {
    existent.find(element => firstOfMatch(element, head)) match {

      case Some(elem) => getElements(existent.filterNot(e => e == elem), tail).map(("Update", head) :: _)
      case None => {
        existent.find(element => anyOfMatch(element, head) && firstOfNotPresent(proposed, head.head) && firstOfNotPresent(existent, head.head)) match {
          case Some(elem) =>  tailcall(getElements(existent.filterNot(e => e == elem), tail)).map(("Update", head) :: _)
          case None => getElements(Nil, Nil).map(existent.map(element => ("Deleted", element)) ::: proposed.map(element => ("Created", element)) ::: _)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

`getElements` returns now `TailRec[List[(String, List[String])]]`, but you can unwrap it by just calling `result`.

Of course, you can nest methods even deeper. Until you wrap your method calls into `tailcall` your stack is safe.

I didn't reimplement your methods like `identicalOfMatch` etc. so I couldn't really test if my implementation works. If something breaks please let me know ;)

Comment: Thank you,I'll give it a try and came back. One last question: there is any danger of stack overflow if I constantly use 2 collection for being compared with around 10.000 elements each? I have only used small collection to do premature testing, because the whole workflow is not fully implemented

Comment: No, because lists is not stored on the stack, but on the heap. But you can, of course, have heap overflow, which will cause `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Actually, it didn't. It gets into a continuous loop

Comment: @user2963757 Can you share more code (your methods, and input data)? Maybe I can figure it out somehow.

Comment: I just used your example and expand for all cases, and ended up with a done(NIl) when the list traversal come to end. Tried to debug for small scenarios, but I find it problematic with this new construction. Anyway, thank you, I do appreciate!